# @Size not working in SpringBoot Controller

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot

I am trying to validate the size of the list passed in my rest endpoint.

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestBody @Size(min = 2) List<Document> docs){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                "Tested",
                HttpStatus.OK
        );
    }
```

Looks like it's not working. I am getting 200 OK regardless of the number of documents i send in the endpoint.

Does anybody knows any way to get it working?

Comment: A GET request can't possibly have a request body.

Comment: Change it to @PutMapping

Answer (score 2):

Try not to use requests body like this..better make a pojo or DTO having list as its instance variables and use @Valid annotation and bindingResult to validate any entity. 
This approach is not scalable.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be PUT since you are updating a resource

```
@PutMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity<String> update(@Validated @RequestBody @Size(min = 2) List<Document> docs) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
            "Tested",
            HttpStatus.OK
    );
}
```

Or

```
public class DocumentRequestDto {

    @Valid
    @Size(min = 2)
    private List<Document> documents;

    public List<Document> getDocuments() {
        return documents;
    }
    public void setDocuments(List<Document> documents) {
        this.documents = documents;
    }
}
```

And controller

```
@PutMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity<String> update(@RequestBody DocumentRequestDto requestDto) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
            "Tested",
            HttpStatus.OK
    );
}
```

Comment: Isn't PUT more for adding or creating?

Comment: No that is when you use POST

Comment: any reference please?

Comment: Here you go https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by adding @Validated to controller(class) itself